# Google API Contacts import getting failed with xml error

Tags: php, xml, google-api

```
$gClient = new \Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName('Login and Contacts');
$gClient->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$gClient->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$gClient->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL);
$gClient->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
$gClient->setScopes("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
```

Creating Google client above

```
    $google_oauthV2 = new \Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

            if (isset($_GET['code'])){
            $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();

            $req = new \Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
            $val = $gClient->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

            **$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());**

            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$output_array = array();
            foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
                foreach ($entry->xpath('gd:email') as $email) {
                    $title = (string)$entry->title;
                    //if(trim($title) == '') continue;
                    $output_array[] = array((string)$entry->title, (string)$email->attributes()->address);
                }
            }
            echo "<PRE>";
            print_r($output_array);
```

Above **$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());** throwing error like 
simplexml_load_string( )  line 7: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 1 and head in app/controllers/profile.php on line 216

Any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: Output the result from `$val->getResponseBody()` and check that it is the valid, expected XML feed.